# Golang const unsafe.Sizeof

Tags: go

Don't understand why I can do

```
const OK = uint64(0)

const OK = int(unsafe.Sizeof(uint64(0)))
```

but not this?

```
const NOK = binary.Size(uint64(0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's explained in the [specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Package unsafe is implemented in the compiler. The expression [`unsafe.Sizeof(uint64(0))` can be evaluated at compile time](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_unsafe). It is a [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).

The function plain function call `binary.Size(uint64(0))` cannot be evaluated at compile time. It is not [constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_expressions).

[Constant declarations require a constant expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constant_declarations).

Answer (score 1):

One thing to mention here is that if the type in question is from a type parameter, then the specification considers the type *variably sized*, so some code, possibly reflection? is run to figure the size.  So using `unsafe.Sizeof()` as such has to do something at runtime to figure out the size, even if the actual type is able to be known at compile time.

```
func [T constraints.Integer] WhatIsTheFrequencyKenneth(n T) uintptr {
    return unsafe.Sizeof(n)
}

fmt.Println("I had to generate code to tell you this: ", WhatIsTheFrequencyKenneth(int64(42)))
```